# How to put data points at center with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm plotting subplots using pyplot and I want the same scale on the y axis for all subplots. I can do that tinkering with ax.get_ylim and ax.set_ylim:

```
if ax3.get_ylim()[1]-ax3.get_ylim()[0] < ax1.get_ylim()[1]-ax1.get_ylim()[0]:
    ax3.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
else:
    ax1.set_ylim(ax3.get_ylim())
```

The problem is I end up with plots where the data points are not centered. I can't upload an image to show what I mean, but when I apply set_ylim to one of the subplots the points end up very close to the bottom or to the top of the plot, which is inconvenient.
How to center my data **without** changing the scale (i.e. without changing ymax-ymin)?

A subsidiary question: I find that the default y-limits are sometimes too tight, is there an option to automatically increase the padding between the axis limits and the data limits?

I can't seem to find a simple answer to these questions in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Concerning the first question "How to center my data without changing the scale", it pretty unclear what you mean by that. Please explain it better and provide a [mcve] which shows the issue. Concerning the second question, use [`plt.margins`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html).

Comment: Thank you, I added some detail. I looked at plt.margins but it seems I'd need to specify it individually for each subplot. Additionally, I'd need to provide specific values for the margin. I was hoping for a more general option like the opposite of [plt.axis('tight')](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis) . plt.axis('loose') or something...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to share the axes. See, e.g. the [shared_axis_demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html).

In order to apply the margins to all plots in the script, you may use [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#set margins for all plots in this script.
plt.rcParams["axes.xmargin"] = 0.1
plt.rcParams["axes.ymargin"] = 0.1

#produce subplots with shared axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    x = np.random.normal(i, size=10)
    y = np.random.normal(4-i, size=10)
    ax.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The sharey option is much more efficient than what I was doing. However axes.xmargin is not in the list of valid parameters I can use with rcParams. And anyway it doesn't help in my case: it does add margin to the x-axis but not to the y-axis (even with the maximum value of 1). That may be because I've got very small intervals on my y-axis.

Comment: Margins are independent of the scale (or intervals). The rcParam `axes.xmargin` adds margin to the **x** axis, `axes.ymargin` adds margin to the **y** axis. If you cannot set those, your version of matplotlib is really old and you should consider updating.

Comment: The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html) on plt.margins says: _if xmargin is not None, then xmargin times the X data interval will be added to each end_ . When the y-axis is shared, one of my plots has a y scale much larger than the data interval plotted. So if I get this right, the result is that the margin, which is proportional to the data interval, is very small compared to the actual scale of the plot.

Comment: So you do understand the difference between `x` and `y`? They have nothing to do with each other! Apart I will not discuss more about an issue without seeing the respective [mcve].